# Transform dataframe column of comma separated items to list of lists

Tags: python, dataset, transform

I want to transform a dataframe where in column 'predictors' I have a list of items comma separated, into a list of lists, like:

**[[Item_1,Item_2], [Item_3,Item_4,Item_5]]**

Any suggestion please?

[image]

Comment: What is the type of the items themselves?

Comment: Items are strings separated by comma, ex: beer, milk, bread, etc. I need that all items in a row to be contained into a separated list and all lists into one container list

Comment: @FlorianC: Probably you want `JSON` output? Read about [module-json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#module-json)

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if you still need it, but here's a solution:

```
result = [ss.split(',') for ss in df.predictors] # df is your dataframe
```